# C# Generics Samples

Tags: web, reference

Like Linq 101 samples form Microsoft site,is there any site shows examples on Generics?

or like albhari on threading can i get any ebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a [Generics Sample](http://tinyurl.com/ykyoy36) as part of its collection of [Visual C# Samples](http://tinyurl.com/yfnupxq).

Chapter Three of C# 3.0 in a Nutshell has a section on generics which has an associated [page of samples](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/ch03.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good site for starting out with generics

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031024.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think generics aren't such a complicated topic as LINQ or also threading. What is pretty interesting about them are the constraints, which you can read about here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic4